# Is it possible to specify location of MS Access .ldb file?

Tags: microsoft-access

I have MS Access databases under c:\program files and we plan to make this directory read only in the future. This will stop the MDB/MDE files from opening as Access won't be able to write the lock file.

Can one specify a separate directory for the LDB file, or even stop it being created somehow?

Thanks for any help